# Comparator Implementation

Tags: java, comparator

I am having a problem with understanding and using the Comparator I have been asked the following:

Create a CompanyDataBase class.

public java.util.ArrayList sortByName() You'll need to use a Comparator object for this.

I have written this method in the class.

```
     @Override
   public int sortByName(Employee name1, Employee name2)
   {
      return (int) (name1.super.getName() - name2.super.getName());   
   }
```

And this seperate Comparator class:

import java.util.*;

```
public class EmployeeNameComparator implements Comparator<Employee> 
{


   public int compare(Employee first, Employee second)
   {
      return (int) (first.super.getName() - second.super.getName());
   }

}
```

But I obviously wont be using the same "return (int) (name1.super.getName() - name2.super.getName());" line of code in both classes...but I have no idea how to implement it in the sortByName method.

I am using a compareTo Comparator interface in a separate Employee class to invoke an overloaded use of the Comparator object.

Any help, suggestions, lines of code would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Strings aren't primitives and can't use subtraction.

Use the Comparable interface of strings to do this work

```
public int compare(Employee first, Employee second)
{
    return first.getName().compareTo(second.getName());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you mean my method in the Comparator should look like this: `public int compare(Employee first, Employee second)
   {
      return first.super.getName().compareTo(second.super.getName()); - 
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two Strings ... so you can (if they are not null) do this:

```
name1.compareTo(name2);
```

Now you need to take nulls into account ... so your comparator would look something like this:

```
public class EmployeeNameComparator implements Comparator<Employee> 
{
   public int compare(Employee first, Employee second)
   {
      if (first != null && second != null) {
           if (first.getName() != null) {
               return first.getName().compareTo(second.getName());
           }
      }
.. other cases here


   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you..I will use this method for my Comparator to cover all bases..and in for learning exercise to try to fully understand the implementation of the code (brand new to all things inheritance, polymorphism, interfaces etc..painful learning experience!!)